# Highlight high to low numbers in a row in PowerBI

Tags: powerbi, highlight

i have a table, Partner Group is common from one excel file
then i have 4 more files with dates: dec '18, dec '19, jan '20. feb '20

the four excel files in powerbi are connected via the partner group file.

i have no idea how to get it to highlight the row based on high to low. i have tried many ways but it wont work

Comment: I'd suggest you add some screenshots and/or example data about the issue. At the moment it's a bit difficult to understand what's the problem and what's the desired result (for me at least)

Comment: Just click the dropdown of the values in your table and select `Conditional Formatting`